# SQL insertion is done but ajax retrieves error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following **javascript** code:

```
var value = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "receive.php",
        data: $('#something').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        async: true
    }).success(function(){
    }).error(function() {
        alert("not sent");
    });
```

and **PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['the_thingy'])){

    $allowed = 100;

    $the_thingy = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['the_thingy']);

    $query = "SELECT another thingy from the database";

    $the_thingy_length = strlen($the_thingy);

    if($the_thingy_length <= $allowed){


        $query = "INSERT INTO thingyes VALUES '$the_thingy'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);



    }

//amongst other queries and of the same "type"
```

basically what happens is that the insertion is done indeed but for some reason it appears as doubled in the database (2x a query done one single time). The ajax retrieves **alert("not sent");** and the page refreshes (which is not supposed). What might be causing this? Other queries, code syntax, certain functions? All other ajax I use work just fine. Is this a known problem due to something specific? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you need to prevent the default action of your form. Can you post the complete code where the ajax is triggered? And check the error log for php errors.

Comment: @jeroen I can't, the piece of code is really extralarge and will appear unrelated or confusing with the variable names. How exactly can I **prevent the default action of the form**? I never did so and every ajax worked... this one in particular is different, the form **#something** is made out of 4 textareas that take massive amounts of text and which are then submitted. It's kept as **TEXT** in mysql and it seems to be uploading correctly (not sliced)...

Comment: See my answer, the ajax is working, but so is the normal form submission if you don't stop it so you get a double submission (and a page refresh...).

Answer (score 1):

For the double submission and page refresh, it sounds like you need to prevent the default action of the form:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(event) {
  // prevent the default submit
  event.preventDefault();

  // do your other stuff

  // your ajax call
  var value = $.ajax({
       ...
    });
});
```

If the entries get added correctly but you get to your error function just the same, it is possible that you have an error in your php that causes the script to exit with an error (somewhere after the insert section).

You should enable error handling and display to see it in the network tab of your browser tools (or disable the ajax temporarily to submit normally and see the error in the browser) or check the web-server error log for messages.